# remove .php from url with rewrite rule

Tags: php, nginx

I want to rewrite the url in nginx so that the `.php` extension can be omitted.

This is what I have, but this isn't working for me. Anyone any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

```
  server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;       
}

server {
        listen   80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;
        server_name www.example.com;
        error_page 404 http://www.example.com/404.php;
        autoindex off;
        error_log  /usr/share/nginx/www/nginx_error.log  warn;

   location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

this is my whole config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Makromat I think the 404 issue you are mentioning in the comments is that your `/` location is resolving to `/.php` without a file name, so to solve it we might add another location just to handle this special case

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
}
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
```

Try this and tell me if it works

**EDIT:**

Ok scratch that, I have a better idea, the first case will fail if the original URL already contains the `.php` extension so it's better to define it as a fall back solution, try this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/;
}
```

Try replace this with your current php block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: Your first solution relative working but I don't have any css style. Redirections working but when I click to one of menu item (only one from 5 items) imediatelly is downloaded php file but other four menu items working properly :D this is really crazy. (I love .htaccess)

Comment: when I trying your second solution... If I click to any menu item my browser download php file...

Comment: what's your php block in the config

Comment: look now I have edited code ...this is my whole config file Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I always use a minimal php block, try using the one I've added to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for bother you but still not working now show me: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Now working me :) But my images and css styles is not loaded... Do you have some idea why ?

Comment: Yes I see in developer tools (network tab) error 404 but url is correct and files in right place...Without your code working properly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41215/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-makromat)

Answer (score 4):

Spent a while trying to get this to work properly. Both php files and other assets working:

```
location / {

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Is this secure? Regarding this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php and this https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be what you are looking for.

```
location ^/(.*)$ {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
}
```

Comment: thanks but when I restarting nginx I have error: `Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:42
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Oops, forgot the semicolon after .php.

Comment: thanks a lot Deniz!!! Now its working but my home page show error 404... but every item in menu is function... only / not working...

Comment: When I try add to first server block home page with my backend working  properly. When I add this line to second server block there is error in home page and backend... when I try to add in both blocks = 404 everywhere... So I don't know how can I solve this problem :/