# Remove .php extension with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm on a NGINX web server and I would like to remove the `.php` extension from url.

I currently have the following conf :

```
server {
    server_name www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /opt/http/nginx/sites/mywebsite/www;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        #rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    client_max_body_size 3M;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    error_page 403 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/www.mywebsite.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/www.mywebsite.error.log;
}
```

If tried to follow some similar case instructions but nothing seems to work with my conf.

The problem is that this piece of code

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;
}
```

is working well in two cases :

1. The client asks for https://mywebsite.com/page.php : OK
2. The client asks for https://mywebsite.com/page : OK

without rewriting the url !

What I need is to tell NGINX to rewrite the url if the client tries to access a page with the file extension. For example, if I ask for login.php, nginx rewrites 'login', and so on.

It also has to keep the GET params in the url if it has.

So what is the right conf to do that, given that I keep in my code the links to the php files with extension and not the relative urls (I hope NGINX could rewrite them) ? (if I need to set the relative urls in my code I can but I don't want to break my local)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove .php from url with rewrite rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975218/remove-php-from-url-with-rewrite-rule)

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions given on this post but nothing worked...

Comment: Just add `rewrite ^(/.+)\.php$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;` in the `server {}` block, and it always rewrite the url without the .php extension!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this question and the comments, I was able to figure out a similar issue, same result with some additional constraints like not using ifs or try_files. Here's what I got at the end:

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
#    ...

rewrite ^(/.+)\.php$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass    php;
}
```

Major contributors were the lack of break/last in the rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

This will remove both html and php form url .[More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

I tried too many options until one of them worked for me, I was able to remove the extension with this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.local;
  root /var/www/vhosts/example/httpdocs;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ext;
  }

  location ~ \/\.php {
    rewrite "^(.*)\/.php" $1.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location @ext {
    rewrite "^(.*)$" $1.php;
  }
}
```