# Disable .php extension but run files without .php as php file

Tags: url, nginx, php-7

I am facing an issue in URL rewrite in NGINX and PHP7 enabled with FastCGI.

The requirement is given below.

Original URL: http://example.com/somename1.php
Response: It will throw 404 error

Original URL: http://example.com/somename1
Response: It will execute http://example.com/somename1.php

Original URL: http://example.com or http://example.com/
Response: It will execute http://example.com/index.php

I have gone through the following URLs but they do not suffice the needs stated above.

1. [How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)
2. [remove .php from url with rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975218/remove-php-from-url-with-rewrite-rule)
3. [remove .php extension from url in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383539/remove-php-extension-from-url-in-nginx)

Sample "default" file's content is given below.

```
server {  
    listen 80 default_server;  
    listen [::]:80 default_server;  
    root /var/www/html;  
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;  
    server_name _;  
    location / {  
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
    }  
    location ~ \.php$ {  
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;  
    }  
    location ~ /\.ht {  
        deny all;  
    }  
}
```

Can anybody help me with the issue or point me to some other page where I can get more information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three requirements:

> Original URL: http://example.com/somename1.php Response: It will throw
>   404 error

Use the `internal` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    internal;
    ...
}
```

> Original URL: http://example.com/somename1 Response: It will execute
>   http://example.com/somename1.php

There are a number of ways to achieve, extensionless PHP. The first link in your question uses `try_files`, a named location, and a `rewrite`.

> Original URL: http://example.com or http://example.com/ Response: It
>   will execute http://example.com/index.php

Usually the `index` directive would be used in this case, as per your sample. If the extensionless PHP scheme messes this up, use an exact match location block:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and not helpful to those encountering the same issue. Instead of simply relying on links that might not work in the future the full answer in all parts should be shown here. In other words, what does the server block look like when it's working?